# background-clip: text pertruding over text

Tags: css, sass, background, hover, gradient

The Design I want.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN2K2.png

So far I get this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2X9M.png

Code:

```
$--gradient-text-primary: -webkit-linear-gradient(242.06deg, #4fcc81 37.1%, #14b08b 88.56%);
$--color-text-secondary: #ffffff;
&.--hover-primary {
    background: $--gradient-text-primary;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: rgb($--color-text-secondary, 1);
    transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;

    &:hover {
      color: rgb($--color-text-secondary, 0);
    }
```

I don't know why the background is protruding beyond the bounds of the text.
This doesn't seem to be a browser specific thing. Tested on chrome and firefox, latest version.

Any ideas, or am simply using text gradients wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing the color wrong

```css
.ghee{
background: linear-gradient(90deg,black,green,blue,white);
background-clip: text;
color: white;
transition: color .7s ease-in-out
}
.ghee:hover{
color:transparent;
}
.wrapper{
background:linear-gradient(90deg,pink,hotpink,black);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><div class="ghee">The Overflow Blog
</div></div>
```

Comment: If you remove the background from the wrapper you can see the same problem as in the question - an 'outline' of the text.