# CSS background-clip: text and opacity transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-clip

I have a `<h1>` heading text that has each individual letter wrapped within a `<span>`, as so:

```html
<h1 class='gradient-heading' id='fade'>
  <span>H</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>o</span>
</h1>
```

I would like to apply a gradient color to this heading text. As far as I know, the only way to do that is to use CSS `background-clip: text` and make the text inside transparent, something like:

```css
.gradient-heading {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(239,255,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,182,0,1) 48%, rgba(199,0,255,1) 100%);
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```

Now let's say that I want to fade in and out each individual `<span>` within the `<h1>` heading. With JavaScript this can be done with something like:

```js
function fadeLetters() {
  const heading = document.getElementById('fade');
  const spans = heading.querySelectorAll('span');

  let delay = 0;
  let delayIncrement = 200;
  let numLettersFadedIn = 0;
  const totalLetters = spans.length;

  spans.forEach((span, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      span.style.transition = 'opacity 1s ease-in-out';
      span.style.opacity = 1;
      numLettersFadedIn++;

      if (numLettersFadedIn === totalLetters) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          spans.forEach((span, index) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              span.style.transition = 'opacity 1s ease-in-out';
              span.style.opacity = 0;
            }, index * delayIncrement);
          });
          setTimeout(() => {
            numLettersFadedIn = 0;
            fadeLetters();
          }, totalLetters * delayIncrement);
        }, delayIncrement);
      }
    }, delay);

    delay += delayIncrement;
  });
}

fadeLetters();
```

The problem is, this animation does not work properly. The fade-in/out actually does not happen. Letters blink on and off as if there was no transition. I believe this has to do with the `background-clip: text` CSS property, but I am not sure what exactly is the issue here.

Codepen that replicates this issue: https://codepen.io/mknelsen/pen/vYVxKeb

Has anybody done something similar before, or can anybody explain why this does not work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what worked in my case was a different approach, I ended up using a trick similar to the last example in this CSS Tricks post: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/

```js
function fadeLetters() {
  const heading = document.getElementById('fade');
  const spans = heading.querySelectorAll('span');

  let delay = 0;
  let delayIncrement = 200;
  let numLettersFadedIn = 0;
  const totalLetters = spans.length;

  spans.forEach((span, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      span.style.color = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
      numLettersFadedIn++;

      if (numLettersFadedIn === totalLetters) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          spans.forEach((span, index) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              span.style.color = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)';
            }, index * delayIncrement);
          });
          setTimeout(() => {
            numLettersFadedIn = 0;
            fadeLetters();
          }, totalLetters * delayIncrement);
        }, delayIncrement);
      }
    }, delay);

    delay += delayIncrement;
  });
}

fadeLetters();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  position: relative;
}

h1::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(239,255,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,182,0,1) 48%, rgba(199,0,255,1) 100%);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  animation: gradient 10s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}

span {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class='gradient-heading' id='fade'>
  <span>H</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>o</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `opacity` of something that is already `transparent` to begin with doesn't sound right. I don't know exactly why.

Regardless, such an animation is possible, even without JS. What you need is to animate `color` from `rgba(r, g, b, 0)` (alpha 0, transparent) to `rgba(r, g, b, 1)` (alpha 1, original color) and vice versa alternately:

(See the vanilla CSS version in the snippet below.)

```scss
.gradient-heading {
  background: var(--background);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

span {
  animation: flash var(--duration) ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  span:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: calc(var(--delay-increment) * #{$i});
  }
}

@keyframes flash {
  0% {
    color: var(--color-0);
  }
  100% {
    color: var(--color-1);
  }
}
```

Try it:

```css
:root {
  --duration: 1s;
  --delay-increment: 0.2s;
  --color-1: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  --color-0: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  --background: linear-gradient(90deg, #efff00 0%, #ffb600 48%, #c700ff 100%);
}

.gradient-heading {
  background: var(--background);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

span {
  animation-name: flash;
  animation-duration: var(--duration);
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--delay-increment) * 1);
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--delay-increment) * 2);
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--delay-increment) * 3);
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--delay-increment) * 4);
}

span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--delay-increment) * 5);
}

@keyframes flash {
  0% {
    color: var(--color-0);
  }
  100% {
    color: var(--color-1);
  }
}

/* Demo only */

body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: var(--color-1);
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="gradient-heading">
  <span>H</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>o</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you! That mostly works. However there's a weird thin outline when the text fades out. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know of any. A quick search led to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71071721), which has yet to have any accepted answers.